# record while key is pressed, stop when key is released

Tags: python, macos, keyevent

I am currently trying to make a simple python script for creating speech data.

The idea with the script is that is starts recording using [`pyaudio`](https://people.csail.mit.edu/hubert/pyaudio/), when a key is pressed and hold down, and stops recording when the key is released.

I am currently a bit confused on how i should implement the `while key hold / stop at release mechanism.`

i found this library `keyboard` , but can't make sense whether it incorporates
this form of mechanism?

Comment: See comment of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40649634/determine-length-of-keypress-in-python) question. That might help you.

Comment: Just seem like a bit too much for this simple task @P.Siehr

Answer (score 2):

According to [this code](https://github.com/boppreh/keyboard/blob/master/keyboard/__init__.py#L154) in library "keyboard"'s source, it do provide such mechanism to detect if a key is currently pressed. so you can just do a while loop to check whether user has released that key.

```
#/usr/bin/python
# file: __init__.py
# ...
def is_pressed(key):
    """
    Returns True if the key is pressed.
        is_pressed(57) -> True
        is_pressed('space') -> True
        is_pressed('ctrl+space') -> True
    """
    _listener.start_if_necessary()
    if is_number(key):
        return key in _pressed_events
    elif len(key) > 1 and ('+' in key or ',' in key):
        parts = canonicalize(key)
        if len(parts) > 1:
            raise ValueError('Cannot check status of multi-step combination ({}).'.format(key))
        return all(is_pressed(part) for part in parts[0])
    else:
        for event in _pressed_events.values():
            if matches(event, key):
                return True
        return False
```

Comment: `while keyboard.is_pressed('space'):`
 
gives me error message: 

`raise ImportError('You must be root to use this library on linux.')
ImportError: You must be root to use this library on linux.`

And running it as sudo gives me error message:

`IOError: [Errno 1] Operation not permitted: '/dev/uinput'`

Comment: `keyboard` seems only to work with windows and linux.  Anything that both works on linux an windows.

Comment: @open_ey, Are you using MacOS?

Comment: Is there anything for Mac?

Answer (score 0):

I faced a similar issue while working on a project. Here is my simplified approach using just `keyboard` module.

We can divide the problem in 3 parts:

1. Waiting for Key Press
2. Record while Key is pressed (held)
3. Stop recording upon Key release

The first part is tricky, there are multiple solutions using `listeners`, `while True` loops, `input` and `raw_input` implementations. I was struggling with configuring these implementations and went ahead with `keyboard.wait(<your key choice>)`. This blocks the program till the key of choice is pressed. If you do not pass in any argument, it waits for any key press.

The second part is resolved by a `while` loop which executes till the key is pressed. After the first two are resolved, the third part falls in place as the `is_pressed` has a mechanism which detects if the key is held down/pressed. This is what is pointed out by @Sajuuk in his solution.

Here is an implementation of the code:

```
import pyaudio
import keyboard

def audioRecord(object):
    chunk = 1024  # Record in chunks of 1024 samples
    sample_format = pyaudio.paInt16  # 16 bits per sample
    channels = 2
    fs = 44100  # Record at 44100 samples per second

    p = pyaudio.PyAudio()  # Create an interface to PortAudio

    # Open the stream
    stream = p.open(format=sample_format,
                                channels=channels,
                                rate=fs,
                                frames_per_buffer=chunk,
                                input=True)
    
    frames = []  # Initialize array to store frames

    # ----- Solution starts here -----
    print('Hold Space to record')
    keyboard.wait('space') # Waits for key press
    if keyboard.is_pressed('space'):
        print('Recording...')

        while keyboard.is_pressed('space'): # Records till key is pressed/held down
            data = stream.read(chunk)
            frames.append(data)

    # Stop and close the stream 
    stream.stop_stream()
    stream.close()
    # Terminate the PortAudio interface
    p.terminate()

    print('Finished recording')
```

You can now process these frames as per your requirement. Save it in a file or process the frames directly. Just couple of recommendations, add a `timeout` for the `keyboard.wait()` to avoid the program to be blocked indefinitely.

Hope this answer helps, cheers :)